# Git ignore disable for certain file

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, gitignore

I have a `visual studio` project and i add `.ignore` file for visual studio ignore file from 
https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore

When i commit file it ignore all `dll` from bin folder but i need to upload some necessary `dll` file to `repo`. How can i achieve this.

Not ignore file like

```
AjaxControlToolkit.dll 
CKEditor.NET.dll
CLRIntegration.dll
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really need to have these `dll` files part of your version control, then you can use `git add --force` to add them to your Git tracking list, e.g.

```
git add --force AjaxControlToolkit.dll
```

This assumes that the three `dll` files you listed above **are** currently in the Visual Studio .gitignore file you mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Append this to your .gitignore file.

```
# bin folder being ignored in the gitignore
[Bb]in/

# exclude these file
!AjaxControlToolkit.dll 
!CKEditor.NET.dll
!CLRIntegration.dll
```

It will exclude these files from being ignored.

Answer (score 0):

You likely have your bin directory in a directory that is included in the `.gitignore`. Analyze your directory structure and the contents of `.gitignore` to figure out which it is.